# Node.js: wait for the response from an async call

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, node-webkit

I am working on an API through which i should be able to add a list of user as JIRA watchers (so i am talking to the JIRa REST API)

Here is the function to do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < votes.totalValue; i++) {
        var voter = {
            user  : votes.rawVoteData[i].user,
            value : votes.rawVoteData[i].value,
            email : votes.rawVoteData[i].email,
            fname : votes.rawVoteData[i].fname,
            lname : votes.rawVoteData[i].fname
        };

        // Add these users as watchers to the Jira
        jira.jira.addWatcher(issueId, voter.user, function(err, result){  
            // TODO: Return to callback
            rep++;
            console.log('user='+voter.user);
            console.log(result);

        });
    }
```

The votes object has the list of users shown above. Now the problem is that when i execute this function, due to async nature of node, the for loop gets executed completely then all the async calls get fired at once. (which doesn't work for me since the JIRa REST API does not seem to support this)

I want to change the above code so that i make the call to the addWatcher function for a user one at a time & make the next addWAtcher call for the next user only if the previous async call has returned(. i.e. move on to the next async call one by one for each user and not fire all calls to addwatcher all at once.)

How can i do this?

Please advise,

thanks!

Comment: 'Does not seem to support this' - could you clarify, are you getting an error message or is it just not working?

Comment: it is just not working. The jira rest api has an addwatcher endpoint which returns status code 204 when a watcher is added. When i use the above code, i get 204's for all users but when i go to the jira and check if the users were added, i see just the last user added.

Answer (score 1):

you should take a look at `async` module.

You can use `async.each()` function. The function takes an array of items, then iterates over them calling a wrapper function which accepts the item as an argument. When all the calls are complete, you specify a final function to be called.
other solution can be `async.parallel()` (in case you don't mind running them in parallel.

Credit for [this](http://justinklemm.com/node-js-async-tutorial/) great tutorial